# Enable system() and exec() functions on hosting?

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, clone

I'm a developer and I build client sites on my server and then use a PHP script to clone it to the client's server when finished. I tried this time but am getting an error of

> "Your host does not allow the use of the system() and exec()
>   functions."

Any idea how to enable this? I have cpanel access and the host account is greengecko.com. Installing Wordpress was easy, I just can't run this script!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your host disabled these functions there will be no way to enable them. You can either consider contacting your host to see if they would enable them for a per account basis or if you are using Free hosting you may consider upgrading to a paid version of their hosting for those functions to be enabled. They are disabled by the host for security reasons. Your only course of action however if to contact your web host or try upgrading to paid hosting(if not already).

Comment: Dang, that's what I figured. Thanks!

Comment: You could always try running it on your localhost while you develop it. For example XAMPP.

Comment: Yeah, running it is no worries it's migrating to the actual host that's the issue as it clones the DB, wordpress content, plugins etc to the new server.

Answer (score 1):

Some hosting providers enable the ability to override [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php) settings from within .htaccess (if Apache Httpd) or using a separate php.ini file from somewhere within the hosting account directory.

I am not familiar with your hosting provider and so cannot comment on whether this will be possible. However, I can say that if you are able to take advantage of such a facility, you are probably looking for the [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive.

As a further piece of advice, if you find yourself able to "re-enable" protected PHP functions and this is on a client's account, I cannot stress enough how important it is you remember to "re-disable" them again afterwards (disabling `exec()` and `system()` on hosting accounts is increasingly becoming a necessity as exploits and simple mistakes are extremely costly to server security).

Comment: I browsed through both the php.ini and .htaccess looking for references to `exec()` and `system()` and didn't find anything. I just did the migration manually, but for the future, would I be adding something to overwrite the default of the host, or am I looking for something in the .htaccess or php.ini?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any result if you search for `disable_functions`? What you'd want to do if you don't see that entry (and the php.ini you're searching isn't a system level one, e.g., not `/etc/php.ini`) then you could try setting `disable_functions=`. If you have a .htaccess file, you could try adding `php_admin_value disable_functions ""`. It has been a long time since I've used either setting, but I believe those syntaxes are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Elijah, I too had the very same problem about the system() and exec() NOT inabled in php.

Just download the php.ini file that is in the root of your website via FTP and you'll find something like this:

```
register_globals = On
safe_mode = Off
enable_dl = On
disable_functions = "exec,passthru,shell_exec,proc_open,popen,system,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source"
```

Just remove exec,(the first word in the line between "") that is on the disable_functions line and also remove system,

Don't forget to remove the comas (,) with the two words.

It worked for me.

Mind you, I had created this php.ini file myself about a month ago but I don't know why, by changing the php version in cPanel, the exec and system came back.

Follow also the good advice given here by plasmid87 to putt it back on when finish with creating the clone of your site.

Mario Bruneau

Comment: what did you set the PHP version to?