# How to enable exec function from php.ini at google app engine

Tags: php, python-2.7, google-app-engine, php-ini

How to enable exec function from php.ini at google app engine 
my php code

```
echo 'test';
 $item='example';
    $tmp = exec("python test1.py $item");
    echo $tmp;
```

my python code

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

exec function not working

Comment: alot of service providers don't allow functions like `exec()`, `shell_exec()` and `eval()` etc for security reasons there is no way to enable them but contact them and ask.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980404/enable-system-and-exec-functions-on-hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to run exec() on App Engine PHP.

However, you can deploy a python application if you want to?

Or, as another option you can deploy a python application as a module and call it from your PHP code via a web service URL