# wget not working when called from exec() or shell_exec()

Tags: php, exec, wget, shell-exec

I am trying to integrate a wget command I have written into a php script.  The command recursively downloads every html/php file on a website (which is required functionality that I haven't found in file_get_contents()).  I have tested the wget command in a terminal window, but when executing it using either exec() or shell_exec() nothing happens.  I don't get any errors, or warnings.

Here is the command in question,

```
wget --recursive -m --domains oooff.com --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links -R gif,jpg,pdf http://www.oooff.com/
```

I have tried simple wget commands (not as many parameters) from exec(), and shell_exec(), but they also don't work.

If wget isn't an option, I am open to using some other method of downloading a website in it's entirety.

My code that I have now is,

```
exec("wget google.com", $array);
```

Then when printing the array it is empty

Comment: what is your php code ?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980404/enable-system-and-exec-functions-on-hosting

Comment: @CharlSteynberg the function is enabled, problem persists

Comment: @mh-cbon my code is exec("wget google.com", $array); and then i print the array and it's empty and no file has appeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to specify a path to wget.  New command:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/wget google.com", $array);
```

Comment: make use $return_var to check about that. If not 0, then something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

invoke wget with proper options

```
-q to remove it s information output
-O - to output the request response on stdout

php -r 'exec("wget -q -O - google.com", $array);var_dump($array);'
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case `wget` didn't have enough permission to save wget'ed file in current dir. Solution:

```
$dir = __DIR__.'/777folder/';
exec("/usr/bin/wget -P ".$dir." --other-options");
```

where

```
-P,  --directory-prefix=PREFIX  save files to PREFIX/...
```

ps. we also added `/usr/bin` found with `whereis wget` but in our system it works fine without it